# deploying jhipster on heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment, jhipster

I'm having problems with heroku deployment. 
I changed the version number in build.gradle

running:

```
$ ./gradlew -Pprod bootRepackage -x test
```

- ok ! Then:

`$ heroku deploy:jar --jar build/libs/*war`

- it uploaded the previous war file for some reason ? I though the heroku plugin was some how damaged. So I tried to re install it:

`$ heroku plugins:install https://github.com/heroku/heroku-deploy.
    Installing plugin https://github.com/heroku/heroku-deploy.... !
     ▸    yarn --non-interactive --mutex=file:/home/amfibia/.cache/heroku/yarn --cache-folder=/home/amfibia/.cache/heroku/yarn exited with code 1
     ▸    error Refusing to download the git repo {"protocol":"https:","hostname":"github.com","repository":"https://github.com/heroku/heroku-deploy.@latest"} over HTTPS without a commit hash - possible certificate error?
     ▸`

- What does that mean ?? Then I tried to specify the version of the war file it should upload:

  `$ heroku deploy:jar --jar build/libs/colony-0.7.7-SNAPSHOT.war`
- but it had errors in the i18n - it worked fine when:

  `./gradlew`
- it was perfekt in dev. Now I'm stuck. I had just taken application-prod.yml out of git because I didn't want my email info on github. Could that have caused this problem ? application-prod.yml is in its place but also in .gitignore

Comment: All your actions are correct. `build/libs/*war` is fine as long as you run `gradlew clean`after changing your app version and before a prod build. For the i18n error, give details. https error for github heroku is either a temporary failure or something due to your firewall.

Comment: Testing locally with gradle is not enough to be sure that your prod build works fine. You should run your app locally without gradlew the way it will run on heroku: `java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=prod build/libs/colony-0.7.7-SNAPSHOT.war`

Comment: Turn out the i18n problem was due to the browser cache. Chromium on linux.

Comment: I skipped the 'heroku plugins:install' and just moved the older versions - then 'build/libs/*war' worked as expected.